# Why do we use 5 in the magic fives selection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection

Can the number 5 in the magic fives selection algorithm be changed to another odd number, for example 3 or 7?

How will this affect time complexity?

Comment: Could you please link to (or explain) magic fives selection algorithm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Analysis

Comment: The Wikipedia page explains this choice of 5. In short, performance/complexity trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

5 is smallest amount that gives you linear time. 7 and larger odd numbers could work as well as fives but finding median of 7 or more elements is more complex to compute than of 5.